# Suppress periods from ending brief description in JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF

Tags: escaping, doxygen, markup

The [JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_javadoc_autobrief) setting seems a very nice convenience, so that instead of writing:

```
/// \brief Brief description.
///        Brief description continued.
///
/// Detailed description starts here.
```

You can write:

```
/// Brief description; brief description continued.
///
/// Detailed description starts here.
```

Yet where I have used the `;` here to merge content into a single sentence, I would like to have the *option* of somehow preventing a period from ending the brief description.

When I went to poke through the source a little, I [found a suggestion](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/3f2e8a3067712b025623e4420e6eb161febfd42b/doc/commands.doc#L3232) that you could get around this precise problem by escaping the period.  However: `/// Brief description\. Brief description continued.` did not work for me.

Based on that suggestion, what *appeared* to work instead was "escaping the space" as `/// Brief description.\ Brief description continued`.  I'm not convinced that's an actual "feature" of doxygen, and I just confused it and it ignored an error state.

- Can anyone confirm for me that the documentation is incorrect about `\.` space being used for this purpose?  *(If so, does anyone involved with doxygen who followed the tag here want to file the report about that?)*
- If `\` *(backslash-space)* isn't an approved way to escape space, then is there an endorsed way?  I tried several things it didn't like... such as `&#46;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you will get the behavior you desire if you set [`MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_multiline_cpp_is_brief) to `YES`, and then set both `JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF` and `QT_AUTOBRIEF` back to `NO`.

I have to set this for all of my projects because I am excessively prolix. It allows me to write multiple sentences—and even span multiple lines—within a "brief" description without doxygen cutting me off.

The drawback is that you must skip a line between your multi-line brief description and the beginning of your always-multi-line detailed description. Obviously, that's how it knows when one begins and another ends.

Anyway, you can now write stuff like this:

```c
/// Returns the alpha channel value of this color, represented as a percentage.
/// A value of 0% means completely transparent, while 100% means fully opaque.
/// 
/// According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing),
/// the concept of an alpha channel was first introduced by Alvy Ray Smith in
/// the late 1970s, and fully developed in a 1984 paper by Thomas Porter and
/// Tom Duff. In a 2D image element, which stores a color for each pixel, the
/// additional transparency data is stored in the alpha channel...
/// @return  Returns a percentage from 0 (completely transparent) to 100 (fully opaque)
///              that indicates the color's alpha channel transparency.
/// @see SetAlpha() to set a new alpha channel value
int GetAlpha() const;
```

And get output like this:

> Returns the alpha channel value of this color, represented as a percentage. A value of 0% means completely transparent, while 100% means fully opaque.
>
> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), the concept of an alpha channel was first introduced by Alvy Ray Smith in the late 1970s, and fully developed in a 1984 paper by Thomas Porter and Tom Duff. In a 2D image element, which stores a color for each pixel, the additional transparency data is stored in the alpha channel...

No escaping required! You can use this on functions, classes, namespaces, or whatever. The entire multi-line brief description even shows up in the big tables (e.g., like you see on the page listing all namespaces in a project).

Comment: Somehow I missed notification of your answer!  But thank you... it has been some time since I was messing with that, but I came back to the issue because I am messing with it now.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Based on that suggestion, what appeared to work instead was "escaping the space" as `/// Brief description.\ Brief description continued`.
>   I'm not convinced that's an actual "feature" of Doxygen

It's an official feature documented in the [manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#docexamples):

> If you enable this option and want to put a dot in the middle of a sentence without ending it, you should put a **backslash and a space after it**. Here is an example:
>
> `/** Brief description (e.g.\ using only a few words). Details follow. */`

I've filed a bug report (Bugzilla #[782373](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=782373)) for the documentation about `\.`.

Comment: A fix for the reported bug was proposed by albert here: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6205